# splitting multiple parenthesis groups with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with multiple groups of text enclosed in parentheses.

```
a = '(apple)(banana)(orange)(grape)'
```

I would like a list with the following items:

```
b = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape']
```

I tried using `re.split`:

```
b = re.split(r"(?:\(|\)\(|\))",a)
```

But I got the following incorrect output:

```
['', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape', '']
```

Why is it returning preceding and trailing zero-length strings in the list? What can I do fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall` is a good choice as @felixc pointed out, but you can just do one more step based on your own solution with `filter`:

```
filter(None, b)
```

And the regex could be as easy as `\W`:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = '(apple)(banana)(orange)(grape)'
>>> filter(None, re.split('\W', a))
['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.findall('\(([^)]*)\)', a)
```